# Authorize.Net payments not working in production mode

Tags: authorize.net

I implemented a capture credit card with auth.net and it worked fine in sandbox environment but now I have changed it to live.

```
$response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::PRODUCTION);
```

I have also changed my `$merchant` authentication values to production credentials:

```
$merchantAuthentication->setName(Settings::get('auth_net_api_id'));
$merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(Settings::get('auth_net_api_key'));
```

When using test card I get the error:

> An error occurred during processing. Call Merchant Service Provider.

When using actual card the request does not get handled and results in 500 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Authorize.Net's own documentation](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=35), the merchant account is set up incorrectly. You need to contact the merchant account provider and have then make whatever correction is needed for your integration to work.