# error code 35 : An error occurred during processing

Tags: authorize.net

I am using authorize.net to charge credit cards. everything works fine in the sandbox but changing to production gives me the error "**An error occurred during processing. Call Merchant Service Provider."**
I have verified the production URL, id and key everything is correct.
can anyone help me with this please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [auth.net payments not working in production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782870/auth-net-payments-not-working-in-production-mode)

Comment: yes @JohnConde .the 500 error got solved. It was from my end.
when i create a subscription it accepts a customer profile with a test card and creates its subscription.but it when i use test card for the charging a credit card it throws me an error.